# Extract path for each terminal node

Tags: python, json, nested, xgboost

I have a python nested dictionary structure that looks like the below. 
 This is a small example but I have larger examples that can have varying levels of nesting.

From this, I need to extract a list with:

1. **One record for each terminal 'leaf' node**
2. **A string, list, or object representing the logical path leading up to that node**

   - *(e.g. 'nodeid_3: X < 0.500007 and X <  0.279907')*

I've spent the larger part of this weekend trying to get something working and am realizing just how bad I am with recursion.

```
# Extract json string
json_string = booster.get_dump(with_stats=True, dump_format='json')[0]

# Convert to python dictionary
json.loads(json_string)

{u'children': [{u'children': [
    {u'cover': 2291, u'leaf': -0.0611795, u'nodeid': 3},
    {u'cover': 1779, u'leaf': -0.00965727, u'nodeid': 4}],
   u'cover': 4070,
   u'depth': 1,
   u'gain': 265.811,
   u'missing': 3,
   u'no': 4,
   u'nodeid': 1,
   u'split': u'X',
   u'split_condition': 0.279907,
   u'yes': 3},
  {u'cover': 3930, u'leaf': -0.0611946, u'nodeid': 2}],
 u'cover': 8000,
 u'depth': 0,
 u'gain': 101.245,
 u'missing': 1,
 u'no': 2,
 u'nodeid': 0,
 u'split': u'X',
 u'split_condition': 0.500007,
 u'yes': 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data structure is recursive. If a node has a *children* key, then we can consider that it is not terminal.

To analyze your data, you need a recursive function which keeps track of the ancestors (the *path*).

I would implement this like that:

```
def find_path(obj, path=None):
    path = path or []
    if 'children' in obj:
        child_obj = {k: v for k, v in obj.items()
                     if k in ['nodeid', 'split_condition']}
        child_path = path + [child_obj]
        children = obj['children']
        for child in children:
            find_path(child, child_path)
    else:
        pprint.pprint((obj, path))
```

If you call:

```
find_path(data)
```

You get 3 results:

```
({'cover': 2291, 'leaf': -0.0611795, 'nodeid': 3},
 [{'nodeid': 0, 'split_condition': 0.500007},
  {'nodeid': 1, 'split_condition': 0.279907}])
({'cover': 1779, 'leaf': -0.00965727, 'nodeid': 4},
 [{'nodeid': 0, 'split_condition': 0.500007},
  {'nodeid': 1, 'split_condition': 0.279907}])
({'cover': 3930, 'leaf': -0.0611946, 'nodeid': 2},
 [{'nodeid': 0, 'split_condition': 0.500007}])
```

Of course, you can replace the call to `pprint.pprint()` by a `yield` to turn this function into a generator:

```
def iter_path(obj, path=None):
    path = path or []
    if 'children' in obj:
        child_obj = {k: v for k, v in obj.items()
                     if k in ['nodeid', 'split_condition']}
        child_path = path + [child_obj]
        children = obj['children']
        for child in children:
            # for o, p in iteration_path(child, child_path):
            #     yield o, p
            yield from iter_path(child, child_path)
    else:
        yield obj, path
```

Note the usage of `yield from` for the recursive call. You use this generator like below:

```
for obj, path in iter_path(data):
    pprint.pprint((obj, path))
```

You can also change the way `child_obj` object is build to match your needs.

To keep the order of objects: reverse the `if` condition: `if 'children' not in obj: …`.

Comment: This is really nice!  I'm able to print but switching to `yield` doesn't return anything if I iterate on the resulting generator.  Would you mind adding the yield version with associated call (in case I managed to mess that up)?

Comment: @Chris I added a `iter_path` generator.

Comment: This works :).  `find_path` does need to be changed to `iter_path` in the commented lines but it's nice of you to provide both versions in the first place.  Thanks, this saved me a ton of time!